# What's the keyboard shortcut for OneNote page navigation?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, microsoft-onenote, navigation

What is the keyboard shortcut to switch between Microsoft OneNote pages?

[image]

Answer (score 31, accepted):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>PgUP</kbd> for one page up
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>PgDn</kbd> for one page down
<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>PgDn</kbd> for last Page
<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>PgUP</kbd> for first page

Comment: ah, you got there first :) +1

Comment: This does not work for me in OneNote 2013 - has it been changed? Edit- the 2013 shortcut guide says it should work, but it doesn't for me. I'll just have to look a bit closer.

Answer (score 9):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Page Up</kbd>/<kbd>Page Down</kbd>

[All One Note Hotkeys](http://allhotkeys.com/microsoft-onenote-hotkeys.html)

Comment: BTW, full shortcuts list can also be viewed locally in the help menu (help > keyboard shortcuts).

Answer (score 0):

*Make to select the proper keys:*

- Go to the next page in the section.
  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>PgDn (Page Down)</kbd>
- Go to the previous page in the section.
  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>PgUp (Page Up)</kbd>

*When I was confusing with:*

- Move the insertion point up in the current page, or expand the page up.
  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>↑ (up arrow)</kbd>
- Move the insertion point down in the current page, or expand the page down.
  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>↓ (down arrow)</kbd>

[Keyboard shortcuts in OneNote 2013](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Keyboard-shortcuts-in-OneNote-2013-65dc79fa-de36-4ca0-9a6e-dfe7f3452ff8)